# Specify file metadata content type for Athena Query result in S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena, pulumi

After querying in AWS Athena it's store result as CSV file in AWS S3,
Then I'm trying to get the file using @pulumi/aws package, using `aws.s3.getObjectOutput`,
and find out that Athena add metadata tag `System defined   Content-Type    application/octet-stream` so in the case object that im got not include body ( file content), if I manually change to `text/csv` it works as expected, `body` propertie appear in result and I'm able to parse result.
Is there are option to specify output metadata as `text/csv`?
Or option just create separate call to change the metadata to needed then get file object?

Comment: There is no ability to specify the output metadata from Athena.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.